# Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi i will try multi sort array , display array list base on recent post values, i need order list please find my code and help with us.

```
<?php
 $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'small');
    $comments_count = wp_count_comments(get_the_ID ());
    $comments_count = $comments_count->total_comments;

    ?>
        <div class="load_more" style="color:red;">
            <?php $row_id =  echo_views($id);
            $data[$i]['id'] = $row_id;
            $data[$i]['title'] = $title;
            $data[$i]['image'] = $large_image_url;
            $data[$i]['comments'] = $comments_count;            
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php    
    $i++;
    endwhile;
echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
?>
```

Now showing result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 127
            [title] => test2
            [image] => Array
                (                    
                )
            [comments] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 116
            [title] => test3
            [image] => Array
                (                    
                )
            [comments] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 124
            [title] => test2
            [image] => Array
                (                    
                )
            [comments] => 0
        )

)
```

I need result (filter [id] using ascending order list):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 127
            [title] => test2
            [image] => Array
                (                    
                )
            [comments] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 124
            [title] => test2
            [image] => Array
                (                    
                )
            [comments] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 116
            [title] => test3
            [image] => Array
                (                    
                )
            [comments] => 0
        )
)
```

Comment: [This stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value) answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use usort to sort the array.  You can check the [simple live demo here](https://eval.in/755634).

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){return $b['id'] - $a['id'];});
```

Comment: in php7 can use the spaceship operator

Answer (score 2):

use **array_multisort** array.

[PHP reference](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

**array_multisort** and **array_column** function can be used to sort multi dimensional array using the key,which is ID in your example.array_column function is used to specify the key which is used as the sort order.

syntax:

```
array_multisort(array_column(array_name,key_name),SORT_DESC/SORT_ASC,array_name);
```

Solution:

```
array_multisort(array_column($data,'id'),SORT_ASC,$data);
```